# EJB : does container need to synchronize entity bean persist?

Tags: java, synchronization, ejb, containers

I am of the current understanding as I learn about EJB's in school:

#### Statement 1

In CMP (Container-managed persistence), the container will tell the database synchronize row in database when different entity beans try too access the same row at the same time.

#### Statement 2

As far as I know though, every database has a background mechanism that auto synchronizes every row when there are multi accesses to it. So, when developers program against a database, they don't care about underlying synchronous access to rows.

So, my question is - if statement 2 is true, why does an EJB container need to synchronize entity bean access to database rows? If my thinking is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Oh. more clearer my thinking. Too bad in English, thanks :)

Comment: the first statement is wrong. Concurrency management is delegated to the database.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh. sorry, maybe my sentence is not clear. The real is: the container will SAY to database: "Please synchronize this row !". Not container will automatically do by itself. and I read this in Head First EJB. Please answer for me again. Thanks :)

Comment: "synchronize", in this context, doesn't mean "lock access to the row", but "save the following data to the row".

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, you mean that when one entity bean save data to row, no other can read data at that time ? But I still think when you save data, this row still be locked.

Comment: What I mean is that the EJB container executes SQL insert and update statements, and doesn't explicitely lock anything. The database decides if and when locks must be used.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't understand so much. My question still be here: if database has done tons of things for us, so why container still need synchronize :| And, "doesn't explicitely lock anything" : can you explain more for this please. Sorry for my misunderstanding :(

Comment: "synchronize" in this sentence doesn't have anything to do with concurrency, multithreading or the `synchronized` Java keyword. It just means "update the database table row", i.e. make sure that the data in the database row is the same as the data in the entity bean. I don't know how I can be clearer than that.

Comment: @JBNizet Ah, I see it ! So, you mean is: The benefit of EJB Container is  will always looks up to database to have the newest data instead of cache data ?

Comment: No. That's not what I'm saying. What I'm saying is that the EJB container will automatically save the changes done to the entity to the database when needed (typically, when the transaction is committed).

Comment: @JBNizet I think entity is just present a row of database. So, when you change/update/delete entity, obvious that row in database will change. doesn't need container ?

Comment: That doesn't happen magically. It's precisely the job of the EJB container to make sure that the changes made on an entity bean are written to the database. The entity bean is not the database row. It's a snapshot of the data contained in a database row.

Comment: @JBNizet So. maybe you need you have typed mismatch the statement you have said before ?  `what i'm saying is that the ejb container will automatically save changes done to the entity to the database when needed` : you should change entity-->entity bean, If I understand you right

Comment: Yes, I meant entity bean and not entity. But entity beans are an EJB2 concept. EJB3/JPA is out for a loooooong time, and EJB2 should not be used anymore. In EJB3/JPA, we talk about entities, and not entity beans. If you're a student and your teacher teaches EJB2, then tell him (diplomatically) that his course is completely obsolete.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh. Thanks :) So, the problems that we discuss for a long time just is: container will automatically help us update data from entity bean to database. And this is we call synchronize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're asking about locking.

By default JPA provides optimistic locking controlled with the [@Version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Version.html) annotation.

You should check for `OptimisticLockException`s.

Other locking modes are possible:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjhz.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html

Comment: Yes. exactly what i want to ask. that this row will lock until one process is done with it ! and this is already the database mechanism. So, why container do this again, please answer for me.